# When using an android bundle, why does a serialised stack deserialise as an ArrayList?

Tags: android, serialization, bundle

Serialisation:

```
Bundle activityArguments = new Bundle();
Stack<Class<? extends WizardStep>> wizardSteps = new Stack<Class<? extends WizardStep>>();
wizardSteps.push(CreateAlarmStep5View.class);
wizardSteps.push(CreateAlarmStep4View.class);
wizardSteps.push(CreateAlarmStep3View.class);
wizardSteps.push(CreateAlarmStep2View.class);
wizardSteps.push(CreateAlarmStep1View.class);
        
activityArguments.putSerializable("WizardSteps", wizardSteps);
```

Deserialisation:

```
Stack<Class<? extends WizardStep>> wizardSteps = 
(Stack<Class<? extends WizardStep>>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("WizardSteps");
```

Exception:

> 12-20 23:19:45.698: E/AndroidRuntime(12145): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Stack

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its known [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3847). I surprise that it still exists.

Use generic container like:

```
public class SerializableHolder implements Serializable {
private Serializable content;
public Serializable get() {
    return content;
}
public SerializableHolder(Serializable content) {
    this.content = content;
 }
}
```

If you use `GSON` library, convert your Stack to String and use as single String for Bundle without Serialize. It should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the end I just used an arraylist as it just meant one line of code to the remove the element after it has been read. Stack was the right tool for the job, but an arraylist wasn't far off!

Comment: **Vector** is the super class of Stack - not ArrayList.

Answer (score 3):

Just cast the serializable you retrieved from the bundle to a List, create a new Stack, and then add all the List items to the stack:

```
Serializable serializable = savedInstanceState.getSerializable("key");
List<Something> list = (List<Something>) serializable;
Stack<Something> stack = new Stack<Something>();
stack.addAll(list);
```

Why cast to List and not ArrayList you ask? Because if this is fixed in some Android version, you won't have a ClassCastException again.

Answer (score 0):

I hope am not talking any nonsense!

Stack does not implement Serializable but rather just extends the Serializable `Vector` which is equivalent to `ArrayList`

I am unaware of the real definition of `equivalent` and how loose could that be, but it is sufficient to say that the first super class of Stack that is Serializable is Vector.

Since we see this exception, then I would probably assume that casting the Serializable to ArrayList should not throw this exception. Otherwise, I am talking nonsense.