# How to get a reference to the last backstack popped fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I add, show and hide fragments. Each time I add/show a fragment, I hide the previous fragment and add the transaction to the backstack.

When a user presses the back button, a fragment is popped and **I would like to have a reference to it**.

Why do I need a reference? So I could hide it when the user continues to the next fragment.

**So, how do I get a reference to a popped fragment?**

EDIT-25-04-2013:

Here's code to explain how to add a new fragment, while hiding the previous one. **The question is how to get a reference to the last fragment after it is popped from the backstack (using the back button)?**

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.hide(lastFragment);
fragmentTransaction.add(newFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
lastFragment = newFragment;
```

Comment: I think you are not properly using fragments.. if you add them on top, and on the backstack, why do you need to hide it? please post some code.

Comment: be more specific please. there dozens of different fragmenttypes and "popping" doesnt ring a bell for me.

Comment: Provided code and wider explanation. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: not sure what you mean, can you show where you would use that reference? on your host activity? where do you want the reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use generated tags for each fragment, save the tags in a stack and persist the stack. This way I get hold of every fragment out there - last one in specific.
See the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16220860/435605).

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to do what you described but sadly I think this is the only way. Shocking to see FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener doesn't provide any information about anything!