# Backstack and memory leakage

Tags: android, fragment

I have developed a small API for dialog fragments based on Google support library with very simple requirements:

- API could add (or replace) a modal dialog
- API could dismiss dialog programmatically or user can dismiss dialog by pressing button

Does my API creates a memory leakage by constantly adding fragments to backstack?

```
public class DialogFragmentUtils {

private static final String DIALOG_TAG = "dialogTag";

public static void showDialogFragment(@Nullable Activity activity, @NotNull Fragment fragment) {
    if (activity instanceof FragmentActivity) {
        FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = (FragmentActivity) activity;
        FragmentManager fm = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        Fragment prev = fm.findFragmentByTag(DIALOG_TAG);
        if (prev != null && prev.isAdded()) {
            ft.remove(prev);
        }
        ft.add(fragment, DIALOG_TAG);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
}

public static void dismissDialogFragment(@Nullable Activity activity) {
    if (activity instanceof FragmentActivity) {
        FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = (FragmentActivity) activity;
        FragmentManager fm = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        DialogFragment dialog = (DialogFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(DIALOG_TAG);
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How many dialogs are we talking about since your concerned about memory leak?

Comment: Why won't you just check? Create several dialogs and dismiss them in various ways (back/ok). Then run a heap dump using Eclipse MAT and search the heap for instances of your dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, its prone to low memory, not memory leak though. All back stack `Fragment` are kept in memory with hard references. So if you are keeping a ridiculous amount of `Fragment`s in back stack then you will get out of memory.

Have a look here: [When a Fragment is replaced and put in the back stack (or removed) does it stay in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482606/when-a-fragment-is-replaced-and-put-in-the-back-stack-or-removed-does-it-stay)

**UPDATE:** I see your `DIALOG_TAG` is not changing so you are keeping only one `Fragment` in backstack at a time, because you remove old one if it exists. In this case you might not have the issue of low memory.

Comment: Where is he removing the old one? `dismiss()`ing it is not the same as removing it! I'm reasonably sure the backstack just grows in this case.

Comment: Look at his `showDialogFragment()` method where he calls `ft.remove(prev);`. He removes previous one before adding.

Comment: Oops, sorry, missed it the first time.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it wont leak but to be sure you need to test it. As talkol said, you should use Eclipse MAT to analyse this issue. There is a good guide by vogel [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseMemoryAnalyzer/article.html) and a good guide on the Android blog [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.dk/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html). Create and close a bunch of dialogs and see if it makes a difference.

On a side note why do you use `ft.close()` instead of `prev.dismiss()` in your `showDialogFragment()` method. The correct way of closing dialogs is `dismiss()`.

Comment: I do not use ft.close(). I use ft.remove() to remove from back stack.