# Query with Fragment backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

Say I have 2 fragments: A and B

Fragment A is on top. Now, I add fragment B keeping A in backstack.

Now when back button is pressed, B is removed and A comes on top.

Is there any callback method in A which gets called at this point?

***Note***: onResume is closely bound with activity, thus it is not called. Fragment's onResume() is called only when activity's onResume() is called.

Comment: Yes. you can use Stack arraylist for it

Comment: You need to add your both fragments in `Stack` arraylist from which you can push and pop up your desire fragment.  Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189088/overlapping-hidden-fragments-after-application-gets-killed-and-restored

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but there is no call back, as popToBackStack results to recreate fragments only in case of replace transaction and not in add.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add [OnBackStackChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener.html) to your `fragment manager` and monitor `BackStackEntryCount`

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener() {    
  public void onBackStackChanged() {
      Log.i(TAG, "back stack changed ");
      int backCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

      }
    }
});
```

Once you get this trigger, you can pass a message from `activity` to `fragment A` as described in this article [Deliver a Message to a Fragment](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Deliver) or probably have an `Observer` in your `Fragment` observe an `Observable` in your main `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

onViewStateRestored() is called when fragment is shown again.